# Iterating through large number of objects for collission detection

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5, starling-framework

I am developing a side scrolling endless runner in which the protagonist can fire on the obstacles when collects the ability of firing.
I am using starling and action script 3 .I am targeting 60 fps.

In order to handle the collisions between bullets and obstacles I store all the bullets which are at screen in an array and iterate through every bullet and do the collision test with all the obstacles present at the screen

Now if i have 30 bullets on the screen and lets say 8 obstacles then number of tests go to 30 * 8 = 240
i think its overkill

Can u suggest me an elegant(faster) way to do that.And one more thing I do collission test like this tell me if there is a better way

```
var object_1_rect : Rectangle = object1.getBounds(this);
var object_2_rect : Rectangle = object2.getBounds(this);
if (object_1rect.intersects(object_2_rect))
{
    //they are colliding
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could optimise this is by considering what obstacles each bullet needs to know if it will hit. If the bullet has traveled past an obstacle, then it's safe to assume it won't collide with it and so you no longer need to check that collision.

So, instead of a nested loop checking every bullet against every obstacle, each bullet could hold an array referencing each obstacle once it's added to the stage, and this array is what you use to check collisions against each bullet. Once a bullet's `x` is far enough from the the obstacle that they will never collide, then you can remove that obstacle reference from the bullet's array of obstacle references.

By doing it this way, you would loop through an array of bullets, return each array of obstacle references from each bullet, and proceed to check those collisions. This should mean you're only checking as many collisions as you need to.

**Edit:**

Or even simpler way would be to loop through the bullets first, get their `x`, then skip every obstacle in the inner loop where the bullet is further away than the obstacle.

If you store the obstacles in the array backwards, so the `x` positions could be `500`, `400`, `200`, `100`, `50` and so on, then the further the bullet gets, the less it knows it needs to check. If the bullet reaches x position of `450`, it *knows* it doesn't have to check the rest of the obstacles in the array, and you can skip over the rest of the array entirely.